# how to send data from a temperature sensor to an html file ?

Tags: html, sensors

I use this command in the terminal to show the temperature detected by my sensor `cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005330085/w1_slave | grep "t=" | awk -F "t=" '{print $2/1000}'`
Actually, my html file returns a graph that its  y Axis represents random numbers .I want to replace these numbers  by the data delievered by my sensor but I don't know how ! this is my html file with random numbers

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Example</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function () {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random() * 40 ;
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 3000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function () {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }())
            }]
        });
    });
});
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your client reads your HTML file, it is out of your server and it is loaded with all information that existed at the moment of load (for example, your data points could be populated by the server (PHP?) reading a file written by your sensor, but that won't be dynamically updated on the browser -- unless you write a function (JavaScript) to get information from the server from time to time.
For example, inside your your

```
setInterval(function () {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random() * 40 ;
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 3000);
```

You could write an ajax function to get the latest point from the server. Your sensor could write the temp data to a file that is frequently read by the server as a result of an ajax call. You could also use websockets to update the local page data for every sensor update.

Comment: I am using django !!

Comment: It doesn't matter. As it is, you need to write the sensor data to a file, and on your Django code you can write a function to read such file when the page is requested, loading the initial data points (instead of random). After that, you should have another endpoint ("server") that reads the same file when requested from the browser. How you are going to do it depends on your server framework. I know nothing about Django, but you should look at filesystem functions.

Comment: For example, perhaps you can write code to execute this command `cat /sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005330085/w1_slave | grep "t=" | awk -F "t=" '{print $2/1000}'` and pipe the output to the server response as a result of a browser request -- and write more code on the browser to treat this response.

Comment: Browser calls -> server runs the `cat` command and pipes the `stdout` to the Browser -> Browser uses `x` and `y` data points.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer ! I will try to write a code to execute the command as you said